# How do I accept user input with a multi-line textbox in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I have an installer built with Inno Setup and I'm currently accepting input using the "TInputQueryWizardPage" control. However, this only allows for a single line of text in the textbox. Is there a way to accept input with a multi-line textbox in Inno Setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a TMemo/TNewMemo object and put it on any control (`obj.Parent := parentpage`). You will need to handle getting and settign it's value directly rather then going through the parent control though.